# WordPress plugin JJ NextGen JQuery Carousel showing all items

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using the JJ NextGen JQuery Carousel plugin but it seems to be acting strange. Instead of hiding the images like a carosel it is just showing them all which is making the page really wide. Please see here (bottom of page) http://vabisoftware.com/

Can anybody spot what is wrong with this?

Comment: are you sure about 7.4mb very big website wich takes 2.17 minuts for load in 1mbps line http://i.stack.imgur.com/1jNVj.png ... iMHO hell no also its ugly http://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Fwz.png

Comment: So no helpful answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is adding an `overflow:hidden;` in your `CSS` to the `jcarousel-container`.

**inline:**

```
<div class="jcarousel-container
      jcarousel-container-horizontal"
      style="position: relative;
             display: block;
             overflow: hidden;">
```

**or in the stylesheet:**

```
div#bottoni_container
.jcarousel-skin-tango
.jcarousel-container-horizontal {
     width: 560px !important;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Its the normal way of such sliders to show and disappear images.